How to ask multiple choice questions using pipeline
I want to ask multiple choice questions to the Hugging Face transformer pipeline; however, there does not seem to be a good task choice for this.
I am referencing this:
qa_pipeline = pipeline("question-answering", model="distilbert-base-uncased")
result = qa_pipeline(question = question, context = context)

I know question-answering exists; however, this task requires context where then the pipeline would extract the answer from the context. For specifically multiple choice answering, this method does not make much sense because I am trying to recieve a specific letter, not a word associated with the letter. Additionally, I could possiblely try text-generation, but I was hoping there was some better solution than this. Let me know your thoughts!

You could hand multiple sentence pairs to the model and then infer which one gives you the highest probability:
https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/multiple_choice#inference
In your case prompt would be the question, and each answer option one of the candidates.
